# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when performing a segue to ViewController with a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, exc-bad-access

So I have a setup like this:

[image]

Where I have a custom code reader view controller, and as soon as it detects a barcode, I want it to segue to another view controller with a label and a UIWebView. So far, it works perfectly with just the label being displayed. For some reason, all I did was add a `UIWebView` and added an `IBOutlet` in my Second View Controller custom class and the segue won't work due to the `exc_bad_access` error. The error highlights the following line in my code reader view controller:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self) //my segue is named push
```

Here is my second view controller code:

```
import UIKit

public class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var setText:String!
    @IBOutlet weak var WebV: UIWebView!


    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        label.text = setText
    }

}
```

**SOLUTION:** So I just realized that, for some reason, my segue was running off the main thread. Does this happen in a closure? And, does this mean that you can't perform a segue in a closure/block?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure there is a value in setText?

Comment: Are you sure that you've set the referencing outlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes - I used prepareForSegue to set the value in `setText`, and control-dragged using assistant editor to set the referencing outlet automatically.

Comment: So everything is working completely fine until I do an IBOutlet with my UIWebView. No matter how many different variations I try, it throws `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try to link. Also, I am calling `prepareForSegue` in a closure block - I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just realized that, for some reason, my segue was not running on the main thread. Dispatching to the main queue fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your code,

you have no code to pass the String from CodeReaderViewController to SecondViewController.

Here is what I did(actually for a barcode reader that I did):

```
class CodeReaderViewController : UIViewController {
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "push" {
            let subVC: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
            subVC.setText = <ANY TEXT WHICH YOU'D LIKE TO PASS TO SECONDVIEWCONTROLLER>
        }
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work, please tell me, as this was written right after Swift came out.

Comment: Hi Naoto,
Thanks so much for your response. However, I do have this implemented in my code. This issue is immediately after the code passes to `@IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!` in my new view controller upon trying to segue, it throws an exc_bad_access error.

Comment: @rb612 Okay, thats for clarifying that. You might want to check your outlets for CodeReaderViewController and SecondViewController. There might be an IBOutlet that you forgot to delete, therefore, it can't find it in the ViewController code. I'm doubting it is caused do to the UIWebView in question.

Comment: Hmm...I looked at it, but sorry, I can't pinpoint why it is failing. I would get rid of all the @IBOutlet stuff in the code, as well as all the connections in Storyboard, then redo it. Btw, are you sure it is failing when it reached `@IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!`?

Comment: Hi Naoto - thanks again! I fixed it by putting it on the main thread. Any idea a) why it was running off the main thread and b) why it didn't work because it was off the main thread?

Comment: What do you mean by putting it on the main thread? Where did you change?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already calling prepareForSegue in the main thread but still getting bad access, double check if you are using the correct view controller class in the storyboard.